# "It cannot be too firmly realised"?

Tags: expressions, phrase-meaning, negation, litotes

I am trying to translate a book into Portuguese and came across this sentence whose meaning I cannot really grasp. Maybe someone could help me understand the meaning of:

> It cannot be too firmly realised that every soul in incarnation is down here for the specific purpose of gaining experience and understanding.

From what I know from the author (Edward Bach) he intends to emphasise the fact that 'every soul in incarnation is down here for the specific purpose of gaining experience and understanding', so the first bit of the sentence *It cannot be too firmly realised that* is probably one of emphasis.

I am struggling however to write this first bit in Portuguese, so maybe could you write it using different words and maybe then I'll get some ideas?

Comment: Sounds like "I humbly demand."

Comment: Double negative construction, used for emphasis; means the same as _It is impossible to overemphasize_ or _You can't say it too often_.

Comment: It's like your wife telling you "I'm not going to tell you again!"

Comment: It’s saying that no matter how firmly you realize it, you could realize it more firmly and still not be over-firm.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I get it now and can move on with the translation. :-)

Comment: 'I came across this sentence which meaning I cannot really grasp' is unacceptable. 'I came across this sentence whose meaning I cannot really grasp' is totally acceptable (yes, 'whose' referring to a sentence, a thing, instead of the expected person).

Comment: Revisiting this thread, I've just realised that 'firmly realise/d' is an unusual juxtaposition. More idiomatic are 'fully realised' and 'firmly grasped [the fact that]'. 'Fully realised' implies that every aspect has become understood, while 'firmly realised' is an attempt to grade a binary situation (a single concept/truth is either  realised or it's not).

Answer (score 1):

Firmly realized means very well understood. Too firmly realized means understood more urgently than you really need. Cannot too firmly realize means that no matter how urgently you understand this it is still not enough. It comes out as slightly awkward English to my ears but YMMV.

He means that it is impossible to over emphasize that fact. With the double negative as in the comment the phrase might be; It cannot be over emphasized that every soul in incarnation is down here for the specific purpose.

The usage of this is more often seen I think as a separate sentence tacked on to the end of the claim. This cannot be over emphasized.

Look at Dickens *A Christmas Carol* page one for "This must be firmly understood..."

Comment: Thank you! I upvoted your answer but as I am new to the site apparently my vote doesn't count. Thanks anyway, I get it now and can move on with the translation. :-)

Comment: Ps. The awkwardness might come from the fact it's been written in the 1930s? I've been finding many unusual constructions throughout the book. Thanks again!

Comment: @Sam *Might the awkwardness come from the fact it's been written in the 1930s?* No - and it is not awkward: it is a relatively common construction. **It cannot be ...** = ** It is not possible for it to be ..."

Answer (score 0):

I think that "It cannot be too firmly realised that" is bad writing because "realised" is already pretty emphatic so having degrees of firmness of realisation sounds odd.

What people often say is "It cannot be too firmly stated" or "it cannot be said often enough" or it cannot be emphasised enough".

"It cannot be... enough" is an English idiom which it may not be appropriate to translate literally into another language. The general meaning of the phrase is "it is important to understand that"